# Gridview not executing UpdateCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatecommand

It is very funny because I use the same structure of code in 2 different projects and 1 one of them works fine but the other will just not even execute.

Here is the asp.net code (BulkEditGridview is an extended control that uses gridview as base control so it basically works the same way)

```
<cc1:BulkEditGridView ID="BulkEditGridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
    DataSourceID="titlesSqlDataSource" EnableInsert="False" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" SaveButtonID="Button1">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="siteid" HeaderText="SiteID" ReadOnly="True" 
        SortExpression="siteid" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="block" HeaderText="Block" SortExpression="block" >
    <ControlStyle Width="50px" />
    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
```

Button1 postbacks and even executes BulkEditGridView1.Save();

Here is the Datasource and Button code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="titlesSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxx %>" 
    SelectCommand="sp_getBottomLinksTitles"  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommand="sp_updateBlockTitle" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="siteid" SessionField="siteid" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type=String />
    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type=Int32 />
    <asp:Parameter Name="block" Type=Int32 />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

That code is the one not working, however this one works like a charm:

```
   <cc1:BulkEditGridView ID="GridViewExistingInvoices" SaveButtonID="AcceptButton" DataKeyNames=id runat="server" DataSourceID="InvoicesSqlDatasource" Font-Bold="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="915px" AllowSorting="True">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate> No Invoices to make</EmptyDataTemplate>

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" HeaderText="Invoice Date" SortExpression="date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="80px" Font-Size="11px"/>
                      <ControlStyle Width="80px" Font-Size="11px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Amount1") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="60px" runat=server ID="amount">
                   </asp:TextBox><br/>
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Amount2") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="60px" runat=server ID="TextBox1">
                   </asp:TextBox><br/>
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Amount3") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="60px" runat=server ID="TextBox2">
                   </asp:TextBox><br/>                     

           </ItemTemplate>               
           </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Due">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("payment_Due") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="70px" runat=server ID="tdue1">
                   </asp:TextBox><br/>
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("due2") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="70px" runat=server ID="tdue2">
                   </asp:TextBox><br/>
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("due3") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="70px" runat=server ID="tdue3">
                   </asp:TextBox><br/>                   

           </ItemTemplate>               
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" HeaderText="Total Amount" SortExpression="Amount" DataFormatString="{0:c}"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" >
                    <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="60px" Font-Size="11px"/>
                      <ControlStyle Width="60px" Font-Size="11px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="T" HeaderText="T" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" SortExpression="T" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="25px" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="25px" Font-Size="11px"/>
                    <ControlStyle Width="40px" Font-Size="11px"/>
                </asp:BoundField>                  
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Invoice Description">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="200px" TextMode=MultiLine Height=50px runat=server ID="tDescription">
                   </asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>               
           </asp:TemplateField>                
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' Font-Size="11px" Width="190px" TextMode=MultiLine Height=50px runat=server ID="tComments">
                   </asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>               
           </asp:TemplateField>                    
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="isblack" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" HeaderText="B" SortExpression="isblack" >
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                </asp:CheckBoxField>
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="plusiva" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" HeaderText="+IVA" SortExpression="plusiva" >
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                </asp:CheckBoxField>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="url" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" HeaderText="Print" Text="Print" >
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px" />
                </asp:HyperLinkField>                    
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="urlDeleteP" ItemStyle-Font-Size="11px" Text="Delete" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        </cc1:BulkEditGridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InvoicesSqlDatasource"  runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT payment.id,'Not assigned' id1,plusiva,payment.id, payment.[date],CAST( [totalAmount] as decimal(10,2)) as amount,amount as amount1,amount2,amount3,due2,due3, [payment_due], payment.[comments],paymentform AS T , [isblack],'view_invoice.aspx?id='+cast(payment.id as nvarchar(10)) as url,&#13;&#10;'delete_preInvoice.aspx?id='+cast(payment.id as nvarchar(10)) as urlDeleteP&#13;&#10;, Description FROM [payment],lead WHERE (payment.clientid = @id AND payment.clientid=lead.id AND invoiceId is null) ORDER BY [date]" 
        UpdateCommand="sp_updateInvoiceN" UpdateCommandType=StoredProcedure>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="id" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type=DateTime/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="payment_due" Type=DateTime/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="comments" type=String />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Description" type=String />
                <asp:Parameter Name="amount" type=Double />
                <asp:Parameter Name="id" type=String />                   
                <asp:Parameter Name="isBlack" type=Boolean />                 
                <asp:Parameter Name="plusiva" type=Boolean />  
                <asp:Parameter Name="due2" Type=DateTime/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="due3" Type=DateTime/>
                <asp:Parameter Name="amount2" type=Double />
                <asp:Parameter Name="amount3" type=Double />
                <asp:Parameter Name="amount1" type=Double />
            </UpdateParameters>                
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The structure is the same, using the same control, same way of update, Datakeynames is there in both, both executes the same thing on button click event, it is a bit weird, using sql server profiler I can see it doenst execute the updatecommand, and testing the stored procedure from Sql server management studio it works fine.

It is not a Connection problem either because the selectCommand works, and it loads the information from the DB.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's relevant, it is a bit strange, but you have in your working code id of type string:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="id" type=String />
```

Meanwhile in the not working one you have

```
<asp:Parameter Name="id" Type=Int32 />
```

If you really use pretty the same code in your BulkEditGridView1.Save(); method, it could theoretically cause troubles.

Comment: good eye, but didn't work, it is not throwing an error, not even trying to execute the stored procedure at all!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused because you got a custom event on your button.

```
onclick="Button1_Click"
```

The framework will start to look for that event and will think you will handle the save by yourself.

But why do you have a save button over there? You can use the buttons which are build in in the the gridview control. You can activate the edit option in the properties or wizard.

Because if you want to use your own controls then you will need one on each row so you will need to add a templaterow and add the button in there.

---

Well i think it's normal that nothing is happening. The property you used of the gridview to link it to the button is used when the button is inside your gridview i think.

Now that i know what you are looking for i would suggest you take a look at this tutorial.
It discusses the same thing you try to accomplish.
[Link](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/azamsharp/archive/2006/11/08/Show-all-GridView-Rows-in-EditMode.aspx)!

Comment: well I got the onclick event on the c# code, taking it off still does the same, it is like nothing is happening, however the Button_click is in fact executed, just to try I added  Response.Write("EXECUTED"); to the code and it did run and print out on the page, so it runs, but the Save() method is not doing a thing.

Comment: I use this special control to bulk edit, I need to edit all the information from all rows at once, and another information on the page as well at the same time, with only One button click. thats why I'm not using the normal edit/update buttons from the gridview

Comment: Hope this is what you were looking for